# How do I recreate this shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Could anyone please help? I'm wondering how to recreate the shape below using Adobe Illustrator. I've tried using the Warp options but I can't seem to get it right.

[image: Light Bulb]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with a circle (using the Ellipse Tool).

Select the top right path segment (don't select any anchor points; only the segment between the points) with the Direct Selection Tool and delete.

You'll have something like this:

[image]

Use the Pen Tool to continue the longer path (holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to constrain the path):

[image]

Do the same for the other end of the path:

[image]